# Is there a way to capture the executed SQL statements in Hibernate and Ibatis then save them to database?

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, hibernate, ibatis

One of the requirements on my current project is to be able to log the SQL statement generated by either Hibernate or Ibatis, and save them to a specific table (on SQLServer), so an administrator can come back and see what queries were run and who ran them, or even reuse the statements on demand. While I don't agree with this approach, I would like to know if there actually exists a library that can achieve this. I am using Spring framework for my web application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to catch all queries of a middleware like Hibernate or Ibatis, the simplest way is to use [SQL Server profiler](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175047%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) or to create a trace with SQLTrace stored procedures (sp_trace_create, sp_trace_setevent).
With SQL Profiler you can save traces directly to a table, with SQLTrace stored procedure who produces a trc file, you will have to insert them in your table with sql statements.
they are lot of examples on the web, for example [here](http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/tracing-performance) 
SQL Profiler have an option to generate the SQLTrace SQL script once you have defined your trace (File/export)

The SQL Profiler is in the developper edition but not in the Express edition.
SQLTrace stored procedures are in all editions (IIRC).

You can generate the trace script on your developper edition and run it on your express edition.
You can also create a stored proc that create and start the trace on server startup.

Comment: but what if I also want to store information like the name of user who execute the query?

Comment: if your middle ware is using a common login for every user, that may be complex. Plus it may use a pool of connections. If this middleware use a dedicated login for each user, it's easy you have the login name in the trace.

Comment: unfortunately all users use one dedicated datasource in my configuration, so I am not too sure if the server-side solution can meet this requirement, even though it does sound logical to handle this type of monitoring in the database itself.

Comment: I can't trace actual SQL text that executed. What kind of EventClass should I trace?

Comment: Thank you so much for pointing that Hibernate uses stored procedures to execute commands, I was tracing T-SQL events in Profiler and nothing was showing up.  PS: if you want parameters values to show up in Profiler you have to log RPC:Starting events.

Answer (score 1):

There are 3rd party SQL Server tools that can capture T-SQL statements, and store them for later manipulation and analysis, such as [Idera SQL Compliance Manager](http://www.idera.com/productssolutions/sqlserver/sqlcompliancemanager) and [ApexSQL Comply](http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_comply.aspx)

Disclaimer: I work as a Product Support Engineer at ApexSQL

Answer (score 0):

You can do it on the server, with database audit if you have the enterprise edition of SQL Server. Or you can use Extended Events. You just need to filter by the application name, which should mention the ORM. To help you further, please provide the version and edition of SQL Server.

Comment: I am using SQLServer 2012 express edition for development and 2008 express on production.

Comment: I don't know if it is also available in SSMS express, but in SSMS 2012 you've a GUI to create Extended Events. If you want to trace from the server, that's a good way to do it. Some help here : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/microsoft_press/archive/2012/03/21/from-the-mvps-a-gui-for-extended-events-in-sql-server-2012.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I know a way though it's not easy to implement. Make a custom DataSource - a wrapper over a real DataSource like Apache BasicDataSource. It will intercept getConnection calls and wrap Connection returned by the target DataSource. This wrapped Connections will intercept createStatement / createPreparedStatement calls and wrap Statements / PreparedStatements returned. The Statement wrapper can now intercept SQL executions and log them.

Comment: PreaparedStatement wrapper will remember parameters set and log them next to the statement itself.

Comment: This solution sounds like [link](https://github.com/p6spy/p6spy), one of the setups allows a wrapper datasource over the default one, but after a quick glance I cant find if this library has the ability to log queries to database other than to files.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another way to do it would be to enable SQL statement logging in the Hibernate configuration settings, and then "hoover" the statements out of the log files.

But I think that a database-server-side solution is probably the best, because it can also captures queries and updates performed using the database's interactive query tool.